# How to get a specified message labels?

Tags: c#, imap

How can i get a specified message labels?
I'm using imap library with c# ..

Comment: please elaborate, what have you already tried? Where does the imaplib come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mail.dll Imap library](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) for that:

http://www.limilabs.com/blog/get-gmail-labels-for-specified-messages

It supports all Gmail's Imap extensions. Please note that it is a commercial product which I created.